# Specify string length for substring length parameter in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

According to this [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187748(v=sql.100).aspx) article and using the Substring:

`SUBSTRING (value_expression ,start_expression ,length_expression )`

> *length_expression*
>
> Is a positive integer or bigint expression that specifies how many
>   characters of the value_expression will be returned. If
>   length_expression is negative, an error is generated and the statement
>   is terminated. **If the sum of start_expression and length_expression is
>   greater than the number of characters in value_expression, the whole
>   value expression beginning at start_expression is returned.**

So if I had:

```
DECLARE @data varchar(max)

SELECT TOP 1 @data = Data
    FROM [SomeDatabase].[dbo].[MyTable]

SELECT SUBSTRING(@data, 10, LEN(@data))
```

My understanding that because `SUBSTRING` has found that the length asked for is longer than the length of string supplied it will return you everything from the *start_index* till then end of the string will be taken.

for example if:

```
@data = "hey there"; // char length of 9
SUBSTRING(@data, 4, 20)
```

This should return `there`

Is this a particularly bad thing to do?

Are there any caveats to doing this?

Should I be explicit about the length of string to return?

Comment: I don't see a reason why this should be a bad thing.

Comment: I tend to use len(@string) ,when i am sure ,i excluded the part i dont want to return and i want to return all

Comment: Yeah to me it seemed that it was legit, it's a really useful feature IMHO

Comment: `SUBSTRING(@data, 4, LEN(@data))` is pretty much the same as writing `RIGHT(@data, LEN(@data)-4)`. However, if the overall string length is shorter than the starting character specified, `RIGHT` will return an error (Invalid length parameter passed to the RIGHT function), whereas `SUBSTRING` will return a blank, which might be preferable.